# Can i use a laravel router and a react router together?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Example ....

i Have route React

```
function App() {
  return (
      <React.Fragment>

        <Router>

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={list} />
            <Route exact path="/p/:id" component={Post} />
          </Switch>

        </Router>

      </React.Fragment>
  )
}



export default App;
```

And I Have Route in Laravel

Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/ov80dm

but when i am try .. i get blank page ...
anyone know the solution ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code as image, edit your question end paste the code as text.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't but you can write a wildcard any route in web.php, so that every route get redirected to a single view where the js is imported. Then let the react router work accordingly.

`Route::get('/{any}', function () {
  return view('base.blade')
})->where('any', '.*');`